# Many-to-Many extra field in activejdbc

Tags: postgresql, activejdbc, javalite

I have 3 tables:

```
person (person_id, person_name), 
game (game_id, game_name)
```

and the linked table

```
play(person_id, game_id, score).
```

With ActiveJdbc I use many2many annotation and it works fine to get all games for 1 person

```
List<Game> games = person.get(Game.class, "person_id = ?", personId);
```

My question is how to get the value "score"?
I tried `game.getScore()` but it obviously didn't work

edit:
I want the complete list of game from 1 person. Here is the result I want

```
game1 | 21
game2 | 33
game3 | 44
```

In SQL in should be something like:

```
select game.name, play.score
from game join play on (game.game_id = play.game_id)
join person on (game.person_id = person.person_id)
where person_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more than one way of doing this, but here is *a* way. You can think of Many-to-Many relationship as two One-to-Many relationships, where Play is a child of both, Person and Game. Then you approach from a different angle:

```
List<Play> plays = Play.where("person_id = ?", 1).include(Person.class, Game.class);
```

By using `include()` you are also optimizing and running fewer queries: http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager.

Depending on your query conditions, you might have just one play:

```
Game game = plays.get(0).parent(Game.class);
Person = plays.get(0).parent(Person.class);
```

If course, you'd be able to get to your score:

```
int score = plays.get(0).getScore();
```

hope it helps!

Comment: ok, thanks for editing my post. For your answer I'm don't really understand. What I want is to display the list of plays+score for 1 given person. I edited my post. But from your answer, I have to get the score from "game", but in my model("Game") I don't have "getScore" method, which leads me to a:  Property 'score' not found on type com.myapp.models.Game. when I use it in the jsp page

Comment: I had a typo in my code, just fixed. Since you have score on a Play, you can get it from  that object.

Comment: ah ok! Got it! Works now, I used the include like you said :) Thanks a lot!